# PHP / Ajax Page Loading / Timeouts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page displaying a catalogue of items on auction. Each has a button to place bids that has a timeout of 2 seconds to check if a new bid has been placed. There is also another script that checks if the minimum amount for this item has been reached. This one has a timeout of 3 seconds.

I had a timer on the page counting down until the auction closes that fired every second but this ended up blocking up the resources of the browser and everything lagged. What I ended up doing was calling this timer externally with javascript doing the actual countdown. This freed up the browser resources perfectly.

The problem I am facing is that if people are actively bidding in the last minute, it needs to recognise there is a bid-war taking place and add two minutes to the timer. I have the PHP code for this and it worked fine when the timers were on the page firing every second but now the ajax calls the timer once so the two minutes won't get added. Below is the code for the one second ajax, and secondly what I have now.

The question is, how can I get the second option to refresh the php page independantly from the main page? I realise I probably need it to run like before but that loads the browser again.

```
    
    //ORIGINAL OPTION
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
            
  
      $(function worker(){
        // don't cache ajax or content won't be fresh
        $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false,
            complete: function() {
              // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
              setTimeout(worker, 1000);
            }
        });

        // load() functions
        var loadUrl = "/lot-timer.php?lot_id=<?php echo $rsprod['lot_id']; ?>&auction_id=<?php echo $row['auction_id']; ?>&eye=<?php echo $i; ?>";

        $("#lot-timer<?php echo $rsprod['lot_id']; ?>").load(loadUrl);

    // end  
    });
  
  });  
  
  
  //SECOND OPTION
      
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        
        
        $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data:$(this).serialize(),
         dataType: 'html',
         url: "/lot-timer.php?lot_id=<?php echo $rsprod['lot_id']; ?>&auction_id=<?php echo $row['auction_id']; ?>&eye=<?php echo $i; ?>",
         success: function (d) {//begin success

            //add the pending message to a div on the page
            $("#lot-timer<?php echo $rsprod['lot_id']; ?>").html(d);

         }//end success
        });
        
        
    });
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for websockets rather than AJAX

Comment: @ADyson do you know of a good implementation of websockets in PHP?

Comment: PHP is not very well suited to running a websocket server to be honest, because it's not very good at async, or being used as a long-running process. If it was me I'd use NodeJS or ASP.NET Core for the backend of a site like this, but I realise you may be too far down the road for that. The most complete implementation of a websocket server for PHP that I know of is Ratchet, but you'd find that from a google search in a few seconds anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm too far down the road for Ratchet as well. I don't have the time to learn how it works. Is there anything with Javascript / jQuery that I can try?

Comment: Can someone maybe guide me on how to use websockets to call the timer and have it refresh every second?

Comment: @Alton You could have a look at https://github.com/voryx/Thruway for serverside code and https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js for front-end code. Pretty easy to get started with.